# using i tags in a table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvvm

In a table I have the following inside a row

```
<td data-bind="click : $parent.editContact.bind($data), text:IsContractor ? 'YES' : 'NO'"></td>
```

I would like to replace the 'YES' and 'NO' with i tags containing font awesome images

`<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" />` and `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cross" />`

buit it seems I cannot place the i tag inside a `<td>` tag, can anyone tell me how to do this?

edit:

I have changed it to

```
<td role="button" data-bind="click : $parent.editContact.bind($data)">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" data-bind="visible: iIsContractor(IsContractor)"></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cross" data-bind="visible: !iIsContractor(IsContractor)"></i>
                </td>
```

using

```
self.iIsContractor = function (IsContractor) {
    if (IsContractorBool.isTrue ? true : false);
}
```

but this only seems to return one record, can anyone spot anything wrong with the change?

Comment: if you can have text:IsContractor to test for the yes or no, i suppose you can have a js variable that will render your <i>. Maybe you need to biend it on html and not text.

Comment: thanks, see edit for what I've now tried (if you can be bothered)

Comment: You don't need the parameter in your function as long as you are not using it. WIth this version, do you have your <i> appearing ?

Comment: yes but something must be wrong with the logic.  It only shows 1 record, and shows both <i> tags for it - need to do a bit more digging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like that :

your html :

```
<td role="button" data-bind="click : $parent.editContact.bind($data), html: seeIcon"></td>
```

Your js :

```
self.seeIcon = function(){
    var cross = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cross" />';
    var check = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" />'
    return self.iIsContractor() ? check : cross;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see what you're doing there but I get a binding error in the knockout context window  "Unable to process binding "html: function (){return seeIcon }"
Message: seeIcon is not defined"

Comment: why do you want to do "html: function (){return seeIcon }" ? just do "html: seeIcon" or maybe "html: seeIcon()". you don't need to nest it inside a function

Comment: yeah sorry that's what I'm doing, the knockout plugin for Chrome just interprets it like this and includes it in the error message

Comment: you have to put seeIcon in the same model as iIsContractor.

Comment: it's in the same model.  I'll have a play about and get it working then accept your answer, thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like it may be to do with the fact that I'm doing the binding within a foreach which is populating the table, not got the fix yet but will post an update

Comment: you are inside a foreach but the seeIcon is in the repeat viewmodel i guess ? it shouldn't be a problem. you can refer to the knockout tuto for collections :
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections